# python pandas method "ffill"

Tags: python, pandas

This is my initial df

```
       China  USA
2009    NaN   -9
2010    1.2    8
2011    1.5  NaN
2014    5.0  NaN
2015    NaN    8
```

and then I used reindex method to add some index

```
frame2=frame1.reindex([2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016],method="ffill")
```

I expected frame2 to pass from

```
       China  USA
2009    NaN   -9
2010    1.2    8
2011    1.5  NaN
2012    NaN  NaN
2013    NaN  NaN
2014    5.0  NaN
2015    NaN    8
2016    NaN  NaN
```

to

```
       China  USA
2009    NaN   -9
2010    1.2    8
2011    1.5    8
2012    1.5    8
2013    1.5    8
2014    5.0    8
2015    5.0    8
2016    5.0    8
```

but it returned

```
       China  USA
2009    NaN   -9
2010    1.2    8
2011    1.5  NaN
2012    1.5  NaN
2013    1.5  NaN
2014    5.0  NaN
2015    NaN    8
2016    NaN    8
```

it only filled some entries of my df..

Comment: It forward-fills the new rows only.

Comment: What is your question? Is it why the unexpected behavior or how to achieve the expected output?

Comment: Instead, do `df.reindex([2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016]).ffill()`.

Comment: The docs indicate this behavior at the very bottom: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html

Comment: @PMende now i got it,so the row of 2015 remains NaN,and so do 2016 and 2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sense, it did forward fill.  It brought forward the `NaN` from `2015` to `2016` in `China` as well as from `2011` through `2013` in `USA`.

Instead, do a `ffill` after the `reindex`

```
frame1.reindex([2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016]).ffill()

      China  USA
2009    NaN -9.0
2010    1.2  8.0
2011    1.5  8.0
2012    1.5  8.0
2013    1.5  8.0
2014    5.0  8.0
2015    5.0  8.0
2016    5.0  8.0
```

---

#### Further explanation

```
# Original

       China  USA
2009    NaN   -9
2010    1.2    8
2011    1.5  NaN
2014    5.0  NaN
2015    NaN    8
```

---

Your method did what it was supposed to.  If took values found at existing indices and propagated them forward for all new indices.

```
frame1.reindex([2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016],method="ffill")

                            China  USA
2009                          NaN -9.0
2010                          1.2  8.0
2011                          1.5  NaN  <- From Original
2012                          1.5  NaN  <- And forward filled
2013                          1.5  NaN  <- And here
2014                          5.0  NaN  <- was there in original
2015        From Original ->  NaN  8.0
2016   And forward filled ->  NaN  8.0
```

Comment: it also works,but i just wanted to know why reindex couldnt work.

Comment: @DiegoWu I tried to explain further.  Hopefully that helps.